# How to add multiple different prefixed attributes in XmlDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml-documentation

I have been writing xml using XMLDocument in c#. while adding multiple attributes with different prefix to root element prefix is not coming out in output xml file.

```
// desired output xml
<rqst xmlns="http://example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" SampleVersion="5-1" xsi:schemaLocation="xyz.....">
<rqst>

XmlElement nodeDeclaration =objXMLDocument.CreateElement("rqst");
.....
// fourth attribute code
var objAttribute = objXMLDocument.CreateAttribute("xsi:schemaLocation");
objAttribute.InnerText ="xyz.....";
nodeDeclaration.Attributes.Append(objAttribute);
```

first three attributes are written correct. Fourth attribute is missing prefix which is "xsi" in this case.

How i can get it done? Any suggestion how to correct fourth attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got answer on my own.

```
var fourthAttribute = objXMLDocument.CreateAttribute("xsi",   "schemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"); 
fourthAttribute.InnerText = "xyz.....";
nodeDeclaration.Attributes.Append(objAttribute);
```

This is how it should be